# Visual Studio 2013 Not Running

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have installed VS 2013 Ultimate and installation has succeeded. But when I run it, just a white rectangle shows and nothing happens afterwards. A screen capture follows.

[image]

Has anybody encountered such a problem.

Comment: Maybe the Windows EventLog shows something more interesting.

Comment: Why down vote? It has conflicts with HTTP debugger.

Comment: Didn't donwvote but the screenshot is just useless because it will never be findable by others facing the same problem and searching the web. Luckily Julians answer added an accurate description of the problem.

Comment: @Filburt - Have the same problem and the screenshot helped me find this post! (Google has an image search too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Uninstalling "HTTP Debugger" solved my problem.**

It seems it had conflicts with **VS2012, 2013 & Firefox** and somehow was blocking some network access. After uninstalling HTTP Debugger All of them work properly.

Comment: Vs2012 is running fine in my system. but not vs2013. facing the same issue as you mentioned. but uninstalling firebug of firefox dint solve the issue. what else can I do?

Comment: I don't have the "HTTP Debugger" but I do have the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

I am faced with the same issue. I was having a working VS2013 installation once I created a new login it stopped working.

For now I am adjusting with run devenv from command prompt

> devenv /resetsettings

Then run the reset settings from the IDE.
Tools menu-> Export Settings->the Import and Export Settings Wizard page-> Reset all settings

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug open on Microsoft for this:

> I currently have VS2010 & VS2012 Professional installed on a Dell laptop.
>
> I recently downloaded VS2013 Professional installer from MSDN Subscription Downloads and installed it.
>
> When I try to start VS2013, I see the VS2013 splash screen briefly and then the splash screen turns white except for a single label saying "Visual Studio" and an "X" in the top right corner. No further activity is noted.
>
> If I click the "X", I get prompted to confirm exit from Visual Studio.
>
> I have uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio twice with no change in behaviour.
>
> If I run "devenv /ResetSettings" from a command prompt, the IDE does appear, but with exception stack traces in the initial Solution Explorer frame on the right.
>
> However, next time I try to start Visual Studio regularly from e.g. the Windows 7 Start menu, once again, I get presented with the blank white splash screen.
>
> A large team of which I am a part has already moved their TFS repository and toolset to VS2013, so it is essential that I get VS2013 running successfully on my laptop. I have been unable to find much evidence on the Internet of others experiencing the same issue.

The solution posted on the Microsoft site is:

> I uninstalled FastPictureViewer codec pack, and VS2013 started correctly.

And also:

> There are several things to try:
>
> [1](http://www.beta.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807911/visual-studio-2013-professional-fails-to-start) From the dump file, we see that you're on Windows 7. Did you ever have a preview of IE10 installed on the machine? Try reinstalling IE10, and also try reinstalling KB2670838 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2670838).
>
> [2] From doing some online research, there appears to be an incompatibility between WPF and the Canon Hack Development Kit and/or the FastPictureViewer Codec Pack. Do you by chance have any of those installed?
>
> [3] This could also be a driver/graphics card issue - do you have the latest drivers for your video card?

Source: [Visual Studio 2013 Professional fails to start](http://www.beta.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807911/visual-studio-2013-professional-fails-to-start)

Comment: Man, really I'dont know what else you could do. I suggest you look on that Microsoft page and add a comment on that bug report so that MS can pinpoint the root of the bug. Please give them all the info about your system and software installed

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I found a solution. A heavy one. You delete the version installed with Revo Uninstaller with Advanced mode - in order to remove registries and connected software.
After that I used TuneUp 2014 registry editor and searched for "Visual Studio". It found 900 more entries in the registry. I deleted all of them and installed clean again. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A reboot solved it for me, also after a installation, in VS 2015 RC. It's essentially a log in splash screen, but for some reason seams to only appear with the logo and the close option.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was something to do with a login to a Microsoft account and I think that the white screen is a buggy way of Microsoft requesting that login. Try logging into a live.com or hotmail.com account (in IE) and then rerunning Visual Studio.

Not sure if it's important but before doing the above I seem to remember resetting my VS environment by running from a command line (with admin rights):

```
Devenv /ResetSettings
```

(Anyhow, some combination of the above got me back into VS 2013.)

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

1. Open up *Programs and Features* in the control panel.
2. Then, click Visual Studio and at the top menu, click Change.

   It will open up a Visual Studio dialog, where you can click Repair. Done!